# RAID 5 - disk rebuild and strip data

Tags: raid, hardware-raid

we have a raid 5 with 12 ssds plus 2 spares and one came to fail, now one of two of spares is active and a rebuild is happening:

- in raid 5 data is striped in all disks or it is stored in each disk and the parity in all disk?
- data of the failed disk will ve unavaible until the end of the rebuild?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The data is striped over all disks, with distributed parity.
- All the data should be available during the recovery.
- You shouldn't use RAID5 at all.

Comment: +1 For *"You shouldn't use RAID5 at all."*

Comment: The last point is debatable.  http://serverfault.com/questions/513909/what-are-the-main-points-to-avoid-raid5-with-ssd